# Selenium Webdriver: can't submit text into textbox area

Tags: c#, selenium, textbox, textarea

I've been stuck trying to do some automating tests with AOL mail service (sending text messages). I want to **insert text into a textbox and submit it** but it fails all the time. In AOL web interface, I have to type the message, then hit "Enter" to submit or send it.
Here's how the textbox looks like:

```
<div id="dijit__Widget_66" class="inputContainer" layoutalign="bottom" data-dojo-type="ws/widget/Pane" widgetid="dijit__Widget_66">
<textarea class="wsInput" tabindex="201" data-dojo-attach-event="onkeyup: onKeyUp, onkeypress: onKeyPress, onblur: onBlurTextarea" data-dojo-attach-point="messageInput" style="width: 316px;"></textarea></div>
```

My code of selecting and inserting text into textbox area works fine:

```
IWebElement ele = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div[id*='dijit__Widget'].inputContainer>textarea.wsInput"));
ele.Clear();
ele.SendKeys("Hello");
```

But thing turns to be complex when I want to **submit the text**, neither of these work:

```
ele.Submit();
ele.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
```

`SendKeys(Keys.Enter)` only adds a new line into the textbox instead of submitting and sending the message.
I'm desperately looking for help!

**I've discovered that the command `Keypress` - `Value: "013"` (Enter key) in Selenium IDE works. But it only works with Selenium IDE, when exporting to Webdriver, I receive this error:

```
// ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [keyPress | css=div[id*='dijit__Widget'].inputContainer>textarea.wsInput | 013]]
```

Comment: hmm after getting text in ur text box did u tryed to manually submit that ? --- not good in that just trying to help

Comment: In actual webpage, after type the text, I have to press "Enter" to submit the message.

Comment: hmm so u manually pressed entered or cant u make submit button there ? also i guess its possible to submit itself by setting submit on that button lost focus or interactive change

Comment: Hi Danish, there's no "submit buttton". Pressing "Enter" is the only want to submit text and send message.

Comment: There's "data-dojo-attach-event" attached to it. So I think it has some things to do with Javasript.

Comment: hmm is thss online or u can upload it somewhere?

Comment: I mean in the html code itself: <textarea tabindex="201" **data-dojo-attach-event** ="onkeyup: onKeyUp, onkeypress: onKeyPress, onblur: onBlurTextarea" class="wsInput" data-dojo-attach-point="messageInput" style="width: 316px;"></textarea>

Answer (score 1):

Way too late for this post but for anyone else looking to solve this. Check and see if there is a function or event that is triggered when you submit text to that specific field. If there is, see if you can remove it by executing a script on the IDE.

It will look something like the image below:
[image]

Here's how you can remove events using JS:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('input')[input_index].attributes.removeNamedItem("eventname");
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using `TAB`, not sure if this will work but you can give it a try :

```
ele.SendKeys(Keys.Tab);
```

Comment: Amith, thanks for your suggestion. I tried it but failed. AOL's help section says that it works only for `Enter`